# why normal User can't change password of others if suid bit is set on passwd

Tags: unix

As per suid concept, if suid bit is set on any file/executable file and the normal user execute that command. command will be executed with the privilege of owner of that file/command.

suid bit is set on "passwd" command and root is the owner of passwd. Now if a normal user say "user1" execute the command 'passwd' it will be executed with root privilege. However, he can change only his password but not for others. why so?

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin/passwd` program will check two conditions:

1. whether the current real user ID is equal to UID of the password item/entry;
2. whether the current user is root.

Only one of the two conditions is met, can the process modify the password.

Therefore, what prevents you from modifing the password of other users is the `/usr/bin/passwd` program, not the `suid` permission. Your understanding about `suid` permissions is correct.

See the [link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/passwd-cmd-with-suid-still-i-can%27t-change-other-user-passwd-why-4175608631/). Here is the answer from a Jjanel:

> google: passwd.c
>
> https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/passwd.c
>
> see lines 1056-1069:
>
> Code:

```cpp
/*
     * If the UID of the user does not match the current real UID,
     * check if I'm root.
     */
    if (!amroot && (pw->pw_uid != getuid ())) {
        (void) fprintf (stderr,
                        _("%s: You may not view or modify password information for %s.\n"),
                        Prog, name);
        SYSLOG ((LOG_WARN,
                 "%s: can't view or modify password information for %s",
                 Prog, name));
        closelog ();
        exit (E_NOPERM);
}
```

By the way, forgive my poor English, I'm finding a good way to impove it.

Answer (score -2):

`suid` bit doesn't make something run as root. It merely *allows* something to make the `setuid` system call, to elevate it's privileges.

`passwd` requires root privileges to update user credentials. It does this quite cautiously though - it starts in a user context, verifies stuff, and then escalates privileges to make the system change. It being set `setuid` doesn't have any bearing on this - it merely *allows* it to do this.

If you want to accomplish non-root password changing you should probably use `sudo` to run `passwd` as root.

IF you really want, you could write your own command that embeds a `setuid` system call, but `sudo` is probably the better approach.

Comment: Are you trying to say that passwd does not call setuid system call to elevate privileges?? if so then how can I assure this? is there any config file?

Comment: No, there is no config file. The behaviour of `passwd` is well defined and controlled. Changing it to bypass user authentication would make it a potentially massive security hole.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The `setuid` bit causes the program to run with the privileges of the owner of the file.